# sidekiq_options giving "Sidekiq::Worker cannot be included in an ActiveJob:" for Sidekiq 6.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

**My Gemfile.lock has this configuration:**

```
  sidekiq (6.0.3)
     connection_pool (>= 2.2.2)
     rack (>= 2.0.0)
     rack-protection (>= 2.0.0)
     redis (>= 4.1.0)
```

**and my job looks like this:**

```
class ApplicationExportJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 1, queue: 'high_priority'

  def perform(*args)
    my_service.initialize
    my_service.build_csv
  end
end
```

The docs state that in latest version of sidekiq the worker include step can be skipped and the sidekiq options would work directly. But i encountered the error "Sidekiq::Worker cannot be included in an ActiveJob" which is a known case for the older versions. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `include Sidekiq::Worker` from the job

`sidekiq_options` in ActiveJob does not work with Rails <6.0.2.

with the introduction of ActiveJob, you no longer need to include the helpers explicitly in each job file was previously done before ActiveJob

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, when you configure your queue adapter, you do this in your environment (production):

config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

this will tell ActiveJob to use sidekiq as its *job runner* (the default one in Rails is not suitable for production).

with the introduction of ActiveJob, you no longer need to include the helpers explicitly as you previously did.

Answer (score 0):

watch your class name definition of `application_job.rb`
write `class ApplicationJob` instead of `class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base`